# split string by char C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that contain the following text:
`[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2]`
There may be more than one:
`[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2];[l=9;f=0;r=6;p=2]`

I want to get the array of strings(for second example):

```
[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2]
[l=9;f=0;r=6;p=2]
```

I tried this but it split not correctly:

```
Regex.Split(seat, "(?=])");
```

PS. regexp not mandatory.

Comment: U need to make it with `Regex` syntax? show us result you want to get

Comment: @harry180: the result shows in question, I want to get array

Comment: 1 dimensional array or 2 dimensional array? or maybe you want a `Dictionary<string,int>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string input = "[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2];[l=9;f=0;r=6;p=2]";
var list = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[.+?\]")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: @chridam: Yes, of course. Just SO say after 5 minutes, please.

Answer (score 3):

The below pattern might help you use the Split option of Regex

```
string input = "[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2];[l=9;f=0;r=6;p=2]";
string pattern = @"(?<=\]);";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string[] data = regex.Split(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2];[l=9;f=0;r=6;p=2]".Split(new string[] { "];" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

And then append "]" back to each item in the array...

Ugly but should work.

Comment: You should mention that then OP will need to add ] for his elements inside array

Comment: @niaher: no the first element will be equal `[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2`

Comment: You're right, so appending the "]" should do the trick.. Not the most elegant solution of course.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use regex capturing?

The pattern `\[l=(\d);f=(\d);r=(\d);p=(\d)\]` will capture the values in each array.

Example:

```
private static IEnumerable<dynamic> Match(string text)
{
    return Regex.Matches(text, @"\[l=(\d);f=(\d);r=(\d);p=(\d)\]")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Where(m => m.Success)
        .Select(m => new { l = m.Groups[1].Value, f = m.Groups[2].Value, r = m.Groups[3].Value, p = m.Groups[4].Value });
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var result in Match("[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2];[l=9;f=0;r=6;p=2]"))
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Setting: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", result.l, result.f, result.r, result.p);

    foreach (var result in Match("[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2]"))
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Setting: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", result.l, result.f, result.r, result.p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a LINQ approach:

```
Func<string, string> process = s =>
    String.Format("[{0}]",
        String.Join("];[",
            s
                .Split('[')
                .Select(x => x.Split(']'))
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .Where(x => x != "" && x !=";")));
```

At the very least it works. :-)

Use it like this:

```
var result = process("[l=9;f=0;r=5;p=2];[l=9;f=0;r=6;p=2]");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
Regex.Split(seat, "(?=])");
```

Seems like you're just missing the actual semicolon, and a backslash for the brakcet, from your regex.  This works:

```
 string[] data = Regex.Split(seat, ";(?=\\[)");
```